# Can I use a var or property as image prefix in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, images

In the org mode image `[[/path/to/image.png]]`, can I define a var or something like property at head of the file, such as 'imgPath', and use it in image  like `[[{$imgPath}/image.png]]` ?

Comment: Yes - see [Link Abbreviations](https://orgmode.org/manual/Link-Abbreviations.html) in the Org mode manual.

Comment: @NickD  Thanks!! This is the answer.